# What are the "pinch" marks on steel rods called that stop something from sliding past and how do you make them?

Tags: steel

I've seen these kind of marks on several steel rods, usually axles, but I don't know how are they called and which tool makes them. They are usually used to stop something, like a washer, go past them.
I may need to do a couple of them on a another rod.

Does someone know how are they called and how to do them? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Imagine in a factory, they would have a large hammer punch or a hydraulic press.  For at home depends on how much it needs to stop, might be able to hammer punch small wings if just to make it hard to go past, or up to welding a stop onto the rod.

Comment: I would call them "crimps".

Comment: They're relatively easy to do on a tube with a heavy hammer, but on a solid rod that's going to be quite difficult to do by hand.

Answer (score 21):

If you are not making 10,000 rods per day, you don't do this, you stop the thing you are trying to stop by drilling a hole through the rod and inserting a pin, typically a cotter pin or hairpin. Or applying a stop-collar with a set-screw.

If you are making 10,000 rods per day, you put the correct die in a punch press, grab the safety paddles and hit the actuator.

If you have a unresolvable perceived need to make this sort of deformation at home, put the rod in your forge and the appropriate die-set in your hardie-hole. In your anvil, which, of course, you have along with the forge and a whole lot of hammers.

Comment: +1 If you have a lathe you can turn a groove and use a [retaining clip](https://www.mcmaster.com/retaining-clips/). Even easier (but much less reliable) and requiring no lathe, use a push-on [retaining cap](https://www.mcmaster.com/retaining-clips/push-on-retaining-caps/).

Comment: I am not 100% sure that putting a "generic" steel rod in a lathe is a good idea. Depending on how true the rod is, results can range from ok to disastrous just turning on the machine.

Comment: @VladimirCravero If you know how to use a lathe correctly, "generic steel rods" are fairly common starting points. Making them "true" is frequently part of making a part on the lathe, so ones that are not true to start with are also pretty normal.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany OTOH these crimps are sometimes used to prevent rotation against the rod (e.g. if a screwdriver handle is moulded over the  shaft), which a turned solution is less likely to do well.

Comment: @VladimirCravero   You would only have maybe a cm sticking out of the chuck or collet to turn the groove, and you'd probably use a carbide groove tool, but you do need to pay attention to the other end if it's a long rod. "Whip" [is a thing](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/hmt-forum/lathe_whipping_sign.jpg).

Comment: @Sphero do not need a lathe for that, just a drill press and a hacksaw blade.   I got that from watching Wintergaten Marble Machine build videos.